# Sum of columns in c# arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, sum, max

```
static int[,] matrix ={
                          { 4, 6, 9, 2, 5, 7},
                          { 4, 7, 5, 3, 7, 5},
                          { 4, 2, 6, 9, 1, 6}

                         };

static int rowLength = matrix.GetLength(0);
static int colLength = matrix.GetLength(1);       

public static void Main(string[] args) {
            displayMatrix();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }//end Main

static void displayMatrix() { // Display The matrix
for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", matrix[i, j]));
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }// end displayMatrix
```

I'm stumped on how to calculate the sum of each column, I then want to display the column sum with maximum value.
I'm not sure whether to use a set of nested functions inside my already existing function, or create another array storing the column sum results? (matrix is also subject to modifications)

Comment: Did you search on the internet for this issue? There are fluent answers for such these questions. It's better do search for the issue before sending a question here.

Comment: I don't see any code here that attempts to do any sums at all, never mind identify and/or display the maximum sum. I also don't know what you mean by "nested function"; the only thing in C# that would relate to that are anonymous methods (which can be declared inside other methods), but it's not clear how that would relate to your question at all. It's true that there are lots of examples on SO and the Internet regarding matrixes and arithmetic, but your question is so vague and unclear, I'm not even sure which one yours would be a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

for each column I did this. Don't forget declare int iValue=0; and int y=0.

```
    public void TryThis()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                iValue = iValue + matrix[y, x]; 
            }
            textBox1.Text =textBox1.Text+ ("Colum " + x + " Sum=" + iValue);
            iValue = 0;
        }
    }
```